# How can I select rows from a table to add scores

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
Score   activity     user
2      123BE54A342B B51450EDEE7B
2      123BE54A342B B51450EDEE7B
2      FB45EC5D0643 B51450EDEE7B
2      FB45EC5D0643 C1F859FE020A
```

What I would like to do is write a query that will return the score where the users have completed the same activity

CASE 1: In other words for this data:

```
Score   activity     user
2      123BE54A342B B51450EDEE7B
2      123BE54A342B B51450EDEE7B
2      FB45EC5D0643 B51450EDEE7B
2      FB45EC5D0643 C1F859FE020A
```

Activity "FB45EC5D0643" gets a score of 2.

Activity "123BE54A342B" does not get reported as only 1 user completed it

In addition, the activity may be completed by "m" number of users and "n" number of times by each user, but the score should only be reported if "m" users have completed the same number of activities.

CASE 2: In other words for this data:

```
score  activity      user
2      FB45EC5D0643 B51450EDEE7B
2      FB45EC5D0643 B51450EDEE7B
2      FB45EC5D0643 B51450EDEE7B
2      FB45EC5D0643 C1F859FE020A
2      FB45EC5D0643 C1F859FE020A
2      FB45EC5D0643 FDEF34772AAA
2      FB45EC5D0643 FDEF34772AAA
2      FB45EC5D0643 FDEF34772AAA
```

Sum of score would be 4 (the activity was only completed twice by all users)

If you could please provide a SQL statement to get me going in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Oh ... btw ...  Score and Activity come from the "Activity" table and user comes from the "User" table.  How they are connected is the "User_Activity" table, which contains an index to the activity and an index to the user

Like this:

```
Activity    User_Activity    User
Indx        Indx_Activity    Indx
            Indx_User
```

Thank you so much !

Per the comments:

```
SELECT SUM(Score)
    ,Activity.Indx AS 'activity'
    ,[User].Indx AS 'user'
FROM Activity
INNER JOIN User_Activity ON Activity.Indx = User_Activity.Indx_Activity
INNER JOIN [User] ON User_Activity.Indx_User = [User].Indx
INNER JOIN Team_Users ON [User].Indx = Team_Users.Indx_User
WHERE Team_Users.Indx_Team = 'C1401D43-7154-4E92-BA0B-B491137E998D'
    AND Activity.Indx_ActivityDistribution = dbo.Indx_ActivityDistribution_Team()
GROUP BY Activity.Indx
    ,[User].Indx
```

.
The above did not work....

Tried this:

```
SELECT sum(score), Activity.Indx as 'activity',  [User].Indx as 'user'
FROM         Activity INNER JOIN
                  User_Activity ON Activity.Indx = User_Activity.Indx_Activity INNER JOIN
                  [User] ON User_Activity.Indx_User = [User].Indx INNER JOIN
                  Team_Users ON [User].Indx = Team_Users.Indx_User
          where Team_Users.Indx_Team = 'C1401D43-7154-4E92-BA0B-B491137E998D'
          and Activity.Indx_ActivityDistribution = dbo.Indx_ActivityDistribution_Team()
group by Activity.Indx, [User].Indx
having count ([User].Indx) > 1
```

Here is the data it ran on:

```
Score  activity user
1   FB45EC5D0643    C1F859FE020A
1   123BE54A342B    B51450EDEE7B
1   123BE54A342B    B51450EDEE7B
1   FB45EC5D0643    B51450EDEE7B
```

Here is what it returned:

```
2   123BE54A342B    A6F2-B51450EDEE7B
```

much thanks to xQbert !
Here is the working query:

```
SELECT avg(score), Activity.Indx as 'activity'
FROM         Activity INNER JOIN
                  User_Activity ON Activity.Indx = User_Activity.Indx_Activity INNER JOIN
                  [User] ON User_Activity.Indx_User = [User].Indx INNER JOIN
                  Team_Users ON [User].Indx = Team_Users.Indx_User
          where Team_Users.Indx_Team = 'C1401D43-7154-4E92-BA0B-B491137E998D'
          and Activity.Indx_ActivityDistribution = dbo.Indx_ActivityDistribution_Team()
group by Activity.Indx
having count (distinct [User].Indx) > 1
```

Update:

this is the final query:

```
    select @Temp = MIN(CNT) * UAScore
    from
    (

        SELECT [user].Indx as 'UserIndx', Activity.Indx as 'ActivityIndx', User_Activity.Score as 'UAscore', count(*) as CNT
        FROM  Activity INNER JOIN
                User_Activity ON Activity.Indx = User_Activity.Indx_Activity INNER JOIN
                [User] ON User_Activity.Indx_User = [User].Indx INNER JOIN
                Team_Users ON [User].Indx = Team_Users.Indx_User INNER JOIN
                Team ON Team_Users.Indx_Team = Team.Indx INNER JOIN
                Event_Activity ON Activity.Indx = Event_Activity.Indx_Activity INNER JOIN
                User_ActivityStatus ON User_Activity.Indx_User_ActivityStatus = User_ActivityStatus.Indx          
        WHERE 
                rank = dbo.User_ActivityStatus_Finished()
                and Team_Users.Indx_Team = @Indx_Team
                and Event_Activity.Indx_Event = @Indx_Event
                and Activity.Indx_ActivityDistribution = dbo.Indx_ActivityDistribution_Team()
        group by Activity.Indx, [user].indx, User_Activity.Score

    )t
    group by ActivityIndx, UAscore
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how SO works. If you want to do this yourself you can look up some SQL tutorials. It's not that hard. Then, once you made a reasonable attempt and get stuck, come back here.

Comment: Thanks... but if it's not that hard... why didn't you post a solution so I can learn from it?  I thought that was why SO was created ... to help people learn.  I know there is a distinct and possibly a group by in the query... but I can't figure it out.  ... and I have made several attempts and simplified the data set down to something that is easily digestable and readable for consumption here.  There are about 7 different tables that are involved to get the data to the point where I can ask an intelligent question.

Comment: @user3174075  The issue is you need to show some attempts at trying to do this.  Show the SQL you've tried.  My approach to solving this would be to do something like this... `Group by Activity Having count(Distinct user) > 1` but without effort showing what you've tried, we can't guide you to the correct solution.  Notice the `distinct` within `count` to ensure different users..

Comment: The problem is not we dont want help, the question doesnt show any real effort so is very hard to read and try to help. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Think about this for a second:  if you want to show a count of users with the same activity, what value should be in teh user column (there's 2 users...)  So you either can only display a min/max none at all or use some advanced functions to concatenate the rows together.  Eliminate the user.indx from group by and select and you'll be close.

Comment: @user3174075 Do you really need user.indx in the select?  If so this gets very complicated.  If you don't need the customers then this is more straight forward.

Comment: To answer that I would need to know what join is causing multiple records to appear for a user_activity.  I'm guessing it's Team_users.  Which means we have to generate the aggregate BEFORE that.join, OR...we have to use analytical functions (over partition by) so duplicates don't affect the average.  Is this MySQL, SQL server, Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregate query that returns the user, activity, count and score grouping on the user, activity, and score. Feed that into another aggregate that returns the activity and min of count multiplied by score grouping on activity and score.

```
    SELECT activity,
            MIN(CNT) * score
    FROM (
            SELECT user, activity, score, COUNT(*) AS CNT
            FROM Table
            GROUP BY user, activity, score
    ) t
    GROUP BY activity, score
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user) > 1
```

Comment: PERFECT !  Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome. One thing to be aware of is that I made the assumption that an activity only ever has one score. If there's ever a situation where the score is different for the same activity, then this solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Removed user.indx from select and group by.  If you need the user for each activity we can make this an derived table/inlineview and join back to the needed sets based on the activity.indx to get the relevant users.

Think of it this way.  This select should return a set of data which are those activities having multiple users meeting your other requirements.  Then you join this set back to your base set to get the names you're after.  Make sense?

I also added DISTINCT to the count.  As if records exist where the same user can be affiliated with the same activity, my understanding is you don't want to count them twice!

```
SELECT sum(score), Activity.Indx as 'activity'
FROM Activity 
INNER JOIN User_Activity 
  ON Activity.Indx = User_Activity.Indx_Activity 
INNER JOIN [User] 
  ON User_Activity.Indx_User = [User].Indx 
INNER JOIN Team_Users 
  ON [User].Indx = Team_Users.Indx_User
where Team_Users.Indx_Team = 'C1401D43-7154-4E92-BA0B-B491137E998D'
  and Activity.Indx_ActivityDistribution = dbo.Indx_ActivityDistribution_Team()
group by Activity.Indx
having count (Distinct [User].Indx) > 1
```

Comment: what about the case where "m" people complete the activity "n" times? ( CASE 2 in question )

Comment: Think in terms of SET Based logic and operating on data sets, sub sets and super sets and this gets easier IMO.

Comment: I don't know set based logic... I am not a DBA ... I am just a coder trying to get some stuff to work... :-(

Comment: SET based logic is actually math not DBA.   I have a set of all customers.    I can sub set those into male vs female I could subset those into race, the state they live etc.  But those are all just different "Sets"    With regards to your case where m people complete n times.  Isn't that handled by the Distinct?

Comment: ahh.. I get it the SUM is occurring too soon, before the duplicates are eliminated...

Comment: look at my case 1 and case 2 examples... I need to know when activities are completed the same number of times by all people in a team as well as just once by all people in the team - that's what makes this more difficult

Comment: I'll have to dig deeper... but we're on the right track I believe.  Others can chime in; I'll look into it later when I have more time but need to leave for now!

Comment: xQbert - do you want me to put the table definitions in the question so you can recreate the table structure?